# How can i get timezone by IP address in US?

Tags: php

In example,
I have an IP address from US.
I'm using this function :

```
$timeZone = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, "US");
```

to get the location.
I'm getting an array :

```
0 => string 'America/Adak'   
1 => string 'America/Anchorage'  
2 => string 'America/Boise'
```

how can I know from the IP address what is the location that I need?

thanks,

Comment: what API are you using to translate the IP address into a location?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to figure out timezone by ip address, especially if you use shared hosting.

But, if you can install [GeoIP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php), you can make it working like this:

```
$region = geoip_region_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$timezone = geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region($region['country_code'], $region['region']);
```

Read more about:

1. [geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-time-zone-by-country-and-region.php)
2. [geoip_region_by_name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-region-by-name.php)